# Reusing Eclipse run time variable input

Tags: eclipse, variables, runtime

I am trying to create an eclipse runtime tool to diff 2 files.  For my specific instance the files have the same name but are comparing versions.

I created a runtime external tool configuration using p4merge using these arguments:

gen\${string_prompt:File Name} gen2\${string_prompt:File Name}

What I really want is 1 dialog box where I can use the variable 2ce.

Anyone know if this is possible directly in eclipse other than writing a batch or shell script?

Answer (score 1):

In the "External Tools Configurations" window, on the "Environment" tab, create a new environment variable.  Set it's name to `tmp_StrInput` or something similar and it's value to "${string_prompt:Hint:DefaultText}".

Then, in your arguments (or anywhere else) on the "Main" tab, use `${env_var:tmp_StrInput}` every time you want to insert the result from the string_prompt dialog.

The prompt appears and sets the environmental variable before the tool is run, the only negative side-effect is that you have created an extra environment variable.  It does seem a bit like a work around but it works well!

Comment: Unfortunately the environment variables from the "Environment" tab are not available in the "Arguments" tab for replacement using the `${env_var:XXX}` variable. See https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=170789